# Data Not Updating, Only Adding Records When EmployeeID is Not Equal to 0

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult EmployeeEarnings(int? employeeId)  //GET
    {
        if (employeeId.HasValue)
        {
            using (var dbContext = new EmployeeDbContext())
            {
                var employee = dbContext.EmployeeApplications.Find(employeeId);

                if (employee != null)
                {
                    return View(employee);
                }
            }
        }

        return View(new EmployeeApplication());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmployeeEarnings(List<EmployeeApplication> employees)
    {
        try
        {
            if (employees != null && employees.Count > 0)
            {
                using (var dbContext = new EmployeeDbContext())
                {
                    foreach (var employee in employees)
                    {
                        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
                                .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToList();

                            ModelState.Clear();

                            return Json(new { success = false, message = "Validation errors", errors = errors });
                        }

                        if (employee.Id != 0)
                        {
                            var existingEmployee = dbContext.EmployeeApplications.Find(employee.Id);

                            if (existingEmployee != null)
                            {
                                existingEmployee.EmpCode = employee.EmpCode;
                                existingEmployee.EmpName = employee.EmpName;
                                existingEmployee.January = employee.January;
                                existingEmployee.February = employee.February;
                                existingEmployee.March = employee.March;
                                existingEmployee.April = employee.April;
                                existingEmployee.May = employee.May;
                                existingEmployee.June = employee.June;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Employee not found" });
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dbContext.EmployeeApplications.Add(employee);
                        }
                    }

                    dbContext.SaveChanges();

                   return Json(new { success = true, message = "Data saved" });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "No data" });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error occurred: " + ex.Message });
        }
    }
}
```

This is jQuery:

```
$('#listTable').on('click', '.edit-button', function () {
    var employeeApplicationId = $(this).data('id');
    window.location.href = '/Employee/EmployeeEarnings?employeeId=' + employeeApplicationId;
});
```

I'm encountering an issue in my code where data is being added instead of updated when the `EmployeeID` is not equal to 0. I've checked my code thoroughly and can't find the issue.

Can anyone provide some guidance or suggestions on what might be causing this behavior and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your payload for POST request?

Comment: yes
"Id": 1, // The employee ID
        "EmpCode": "EMP001",
        "EmpName": "John Doe",
        "January": 1000,
        "February": 1200,
        "March": 1500,
        "April": 1400,
        "May": 1600,
        "June": 1300
Id is hidden

Answer (score 0):

It is better to check where the  Employee.Id in your employee even exist in the database.

```
if (dbContext.EmployeeApplications.Where(x => x.Id == employee.Id).Any())
{
var existingEmployee = dbContext.EmployeeApplications.Find(employee.Id);

existingEmployee.EmpCode = employee.EmpCode;
                                existingEmployee.EmpName = employee.EmpName;
                                existingEmployee.January = employee.January;
                                existingEmployee.February = employee.February;
                                existingEmployee.March = employee.March;
                                existingEmployee.April = employee.April;
                                existingEmployee.May = employee.May;
                                existingEmployee.June = employee.June;

 dbContext.Update(existingEmployee);
}
else
{
// your code of adding employee
}
```

Comment: it's still not working

Comment: Can you post your view. That must be something wrong with your view.

Answer (score 0):

Plz try the below code:

Seems you're missing

dbContext.Entry(existingEmployee).State = EntityState.Modified;

```
if (existingEmployee != null)
{
    existingEmployee.EmpCode = employee.EmpCode;
    existingEmployee.EmpName = employee.EmpName;
    existingEmployee.January = employee.January;
    existingEmployee.February = employee.February;
    existingEmployee.March = employee.March;
    existingEmployee.April = employee.April;
    existingEmployee.May = employee.May;
    existingEmployee.June = employee.June;

    dbContext.Entry(existingEmployee).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```